# json app crash- due to no network connection and failed to load json text file from unreached server

Tags: android, json

I am using JSON tutorial. It loads a data from server using JSON text file, here every thing works fine. but if there is mobile data not turned on!, and there is no data received from server my app simply crash. how to solve this problem and also that I am looking for alert dialog or toast msg to show network is not available. most important thing is preventing app from crash because of this problem.here is my activity!

```
package app.test.json;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.util.Log;  
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {    
    // Declare Variables
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView listview;
    ListViewAdapter adapter;
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist;
    static String RANK = "rank";
    static String COUNTRY = "country";
    static String POPULATION = "population";
    static String FLAG = "flag";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /* Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.readmore);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,appdetails.class));    
            }
        });

        */

// Execute DownloadJSON AsyncTask
        new DownloadJSON().execute();

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            //mProgressDialog.setTitle("Connecting to Server");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to App Server...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL("http://localhost/json.txt");

            try {
                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("worldpopulation");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                    // Retrive JSON Objects
                    map.put("rank", jsonobject.getString("rank"));
                    map.put("country", jsonobject.getString("country"));
                    map.put("population", jsonobject.getString("population"));
                    map.put("flag", jsonobject.getString("flag"));
                    // Set the JSON Objects into the array
                    arraylist.add(map);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
            listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
            // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
            adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, arraylist);
            // Set the adapter to the ListView
            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connected To Server",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }`
}
```

Comment: post your stack trace

Comment: Share the Log Cat output when the error occurs.

Comment: Are you checking for errors in JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL() method?